# How to take screen shot of current screen in android programmaticaly?

Tags: android

I had designed my android layout with some textviews and listview,after loading screen i just wanted to take screen shot of that layout and i have to save it on my device.Is it possible or not.

Comment: Is passible to take screenshot

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android

Comment: some guys down vote this question,why you are discourage the freshers.

Comment: I didnt downvoted it, but I can clearly see the reason why other people would do it; the question does not show any kind of effort or whatsoever.

Comment: the given sample not working fine,its throwing some error like source not found @ this line bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache()); and also i used View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(); instead of View v1 = mCurrentUrlMask.getRootView(); because its throwing some error

Comment: @AlvaroSantisteban i had tried different examples but they didnt work for me,thats why i posted here with my requirement,it is difficult to post all the examples what i had tried

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap bitmap;
View v1 = findViewById(R.id.rlid);// get ur root view id
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

For saving

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
 File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "test.jpg")
 f.createNewFile();
 FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
 fo.write(bytes.toByteArray()); 
 fo.close();
```

dont forget to give permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: while creating bitmap its throwing some nullpointer exception

Comment: what is the exact exception?

Comment: its an simple null pointer exeption,but i had written this code with in the constructor will its work fine

Comment: I had asked you to can i write it in the constructor,but i didnt get the screen shot

Answer (score 0):

From  [How to programatically take a screenshot on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android)

Here is the sample code:

```
// image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + ACCUWX.IMAGE_APPEND;   
// create bitmap screen capture
Bitmap bitmap;
View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

OutputStream fout = null;
imageFile = new File(mPath);

try {
  fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
  fout.flush();
  fout.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For this you need this permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Insted of mCurrentUrlMask you can use like this  View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

Comment: I had tried but its throwing an error NullException at line bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache()); and i changed these lines in your code String mPath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" +"test.png"; and File imageFile = new File(mPath);